# Spring. How to convert object property with PropertyEditors?

Tags: java, spring, propertyeditor

I have jsp page with Spring form:

```
<form:form id="edit-form" method="POST" commandName="item"
                    action="items">
    <form:input id="title" path="title" type="text" />

    <form:textarea id="description" path="description"></form:textarea>

    <form:input id="timeLeft" type="text" path="timeLeft" />

    <button type="submit" id="sell-item">Create/Edit</button>

</form:form>
```

On the clienside timeleft format: HH:MM, but on serverside we need to convert it to milliseconds (Long). How to do that (From client comes **Item** object with(title, description, timeleft fields))? How to convert specific property in custom object?

I'm trying to do something like that:

Controller class with the initBinder method:

```
@InitBinder
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, "item.timeLeft",
            new TimeleftPropertyEditor());
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void create(@ModelAttribute("item") Item item, BindingResult result) {
    System.out.println(item + ": " +result.getAllErrors());
}
```

TimeleftPropertyEditor:

```
public class TimeleftPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
private static final int MILLIS_IN_HOUR = 60 * 60 * 1000;
private static final int MILLIS_IN_MINUTE = 60 * 1000;

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Long result = null;
        if (text != null) {
            String[] time = text.split(":");
            if (time.length != 1) {
                long hours = Long.parseLong(time[0]) * MILLIS_IN_HOUR;
                long minutes = Long.parseLong(time[1]) * MILLIS_IN_MINUTE;
                result = hours + minutes;
            } else {
                result = -1L;
            }
        }
        setValue(result);
    } 
}
```

But setAsText method not invoking when request comming.
BindingResult object have errors: *[Field error in object 'item' on field 'timeLeft': rejected value [12:33]; codes [typeMismatch.item.timeLeft,typeMismatch.timeLeft,typeMismatch.java.lang.Long,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [item.timeLeft,timeLeft]; arguments []; default message [timeLeft]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long' for property 'timeLeft'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12:33"]]*

Comment: A long is a long not a string. In the init binder you tell that for a String to use this editor. Also you probably don't want to register it for all fields so you probably want to configure it for type `Long.class` and the specific field name.

Comment: @M. Deinum wow. Thanks! Its' working. Thanks a lot!